# How to copy data to another table without overwrite existing columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 tables in my Amazon DynamoDB: Elements and Containers. Hierarchy is that one container can hold few elements.
So Elements look like: uuid, timestamp, container_id, data.
I want to aggregate data from all elements to corresponding container, example:
Elements:

```
| uuid | container_id | data |  
| 1    | 1            | 100  |  
| 2    | 1            | 150  |  
| 3    | 2            | 100  |
```

So I want to get in Containers table:

```
| uuid | data |  
| 1    | 250  |  
| 2    | 100  |
```

So, using hive, I wrote script (that starts on EMR cluster):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE element (`uuid` string, `container_id ` bigint, `data` double) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES("dynamodb.table.name"="Elements", "dynamodb.column.mapping"="uuid:UUID,container_id:container_id,data:data");
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE container (`uuid` string, `data` double) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES("dynamodb.table.name"="Containers", "dynamodb.column.mapping"="uuid:UUID,data:data");
INSERT INTO TABLE container SELECT container_id as `uuid` sum(`data`) as `data` FROM element WHERE container_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY container_id;
```

And it works good, but now I need to write some additional data to Containers table, so it should be like `uuid, data, another_data`. But when I perform script above it overwrite all `another_data` (that are not listed in external table). I try a lot of variants, but can't find solution.

Comment: when you are adding additional column to the containers table what value does this column take for already existing data?

Comment: adding new data it's not high-performance operation, so I'm doing it through java and `amazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(tableName, key, attributeUpdates)` and it's actually puts some data, without any affect on another data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found an answer:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE element (`uuid` string, `container_id ` bigint, `data` double) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES("dynamodb.table.name"="Elements", "dynamodb.column.mapping"="uuid:UUID,container_id:container_id,data:data");
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE container (`uuid` string, `data` double, `another_data` double) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES("dynamodb.table.name"="Containers", "dynamodb.column.mapping"="uuid:UUID,data:data,another_data:another_data");
INSERT INTO TABLE container SELECT element.`container_id` as `uuid` sum(element.`data`) as `data`, collect_set(container.`another_data`)[0] as `another_data` FROM element LEFT JOIN container ON (element.`container_id` = container.`uuid`) WHERE element.container_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY element.container_id;
```